# Processing Video by using GPUImage framework in iPhone programming

Tags: iphone, filtering, video-processing, gpuimage

I want to apply the GPUImageTwoInputFilter to the different frames in one video file.
How can I get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a GPUImageBuffer. This stores and delays frames for later processing, letting you keep a previous frame of video around so that it can be used in a blend or other processing operation with a subsequent frame.

Look at the code behind the GPUImageLowPassFilter, which uses a GPUImageBuffer and a GPUImageDissolveBlendFilter to do a weighted averaging of subsequent frames of video in order to produce a low-pass filter effect.

Comment: Hello, @Bard Larson. I've tested the GPUImageLowPassFilter, however, it crashes by infinite loop in 'endProcessing' function.

Comment: I tried GPUImageLowPassFilter, but always got the same video with the original one. I can not find the reason. Would you please help me?